# Save File code error after running the code

Tags: excel, vb.net

This is the code I used for creating excel file with multiple sheets.  However, the save file code has error when I run it.

```
Dim oSheet1Name As String = "Requisition_Vendors"
Dim oSheet2Name As String = "Requisition_Detail_Opt__Fields"

Dim oSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim oSheet2 As Excel.Worksheet

If oExcel.Application.Sheets.Count() < 1 Then
        oSheet1 = CType(oBook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    Else
        oSheet1 = oExcel.Worksheets(1)
    End If
    With oSheet1
        .Name = oSheet1Name
        .Range("A1").Value = "RQNHSEQ"
        .Range("B1").Value = "VDCODE"
        .Range("C1").Value = "CURRENCY"
        .Range("D1").Value = "RATE"
        .Range("E1").Value = "SPREAD"
        .Range("F1").Value = "RATETYPE"
        .Range("G1").Value = "RATEMATCH"
        .Range("H1").Value = "RATEDATE"
        .Range("I1").Value = "RATEOPER"
    End With

    If oExcel.Application.Sheets.Count() < 2 Then
        oSheet2 = CType(oBook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    Else
        oSheet2 = oExcel.Worksheets(2)
    End If

    With oSheet2
        .Name = oSheet2Name
        .Range("A1").Value = "RQNHSEQ"
        .Range("B1").Value = "RQNLREV"
        .Range("C1").Value = "OPTFIELD"
        .Range("D1").Value = "VALUE"
        .Range("E1").Value = "TYPE"
        .Range("F1").Value = "LENGTH"
        .Range("G1").Value = "DECIMALS"
        .Range("H1").Value = "ALLOWNULL"
        .Range("I1").Value = "VALIDATE"
        .Range("J1").Value = "SWSET"
        .Range("K1").Value = "VALINDEX"
        .Range("L1").Value = "VALIFTEXT"
        .Range("M1").Value = "VALIFMONEY"
        .Range("N1").Value = "VALIFNUM"
        .Range("O1").Value = "VALIFLONG"
        .Range("P1").Value = "VALIFBOOL"
        .Range("Q1").Value = "VALIFDATE"
        .Range("R1").Value = "VALIFTIME"
        .Range("S1").Value = "FDESC"
        .Range("T1").Value = "VDESC"
    End With
```

The sixth row " oSheet.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName) " is the error. oSheet is not in the code itself. This question is actually related to my previous question. I used to declare oSheet only and create 6 sheets in the same workbook but then I found out that it is hard to work with every sheet I created in that way. Which in my previous question, someone answered and suggested me to declare each sheets as oSheet1, oSheet2, oSheet3.... so that it can make the code easier to read and work. Can I know what I can use to replace it?

```
Dim SaveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Execl files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
    SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    SaveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        oSheet.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
        MsgBox("Excel File Created Successfully!")
    Else
        Return
    End If
    oBook.Close()
    oExcel.Quit()
```

[image]

Comment: Assuming that is all in the same scope, what's oSheet in this context?  I can see you've declared oSheet1 and oSheet2 further up you code but don't see oSheet anywhere

Comment: What's the actual error message? Did you even look?

Comment: @Hursey yes, oSheet is not in the code itself. This question is actually related to my previous question. I used to declare oSheet only and create 6 sheets in the same workbook but then I found out that it is hard to work with every sheet I created in that way. Which in my previous question, someone answered and suggested me to declare each sheets as oSheet1, oSheet2, oSheet3.... so that it can make the code easier to read and work.

Comment: @John it says that oSheet is not declared. You can read my reply to Hursey for the details.

Comment: Not sure I understand the response, but I don't see how your previous question is really of any relevance here.  oSheet does not exist, so you simply can not call the SaveAs method.  You either need to update your method to save each oSheet1...oSheetn, or save the work book as a whole.

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem in the question. If you fail to do so in the first place, edit the question to do so later.

Comment: Is this your code or not? If it is then you you should know what it's supposed to do. If you're told that you're trying to use a variable that isn't declared then it should be obvious that you need to either declare that variable or use one that is already declared. If this is not your code, which I suspect is the case, then I would suggest that you need to spend some time understanding what it's actually doing. Then you wouldn't make such elementary mistakes. We shouldn't have to tell you that you need to declare a variable in order to be able to use it. That's fundamentals.

Comment: @John sorry for asking dumb question and providing unclear question. This is the first time I use vb.net and I agree with you about understanding what the codes actually do. Given the time of my diploma internship is merely 8 weeks and this task is assigned on the fourth week, I do not have much time to do self study about programming which leads me to refer and find solutions from online sources. Anyhow, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I changed oSheet to oBook!

```
Dim SaveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Execl files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
SaveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    obook.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    MsgBox("Excel File Created Successfully!")
Else
    Return
End If
oBook.Close()
oExcel.Quit()
```